# What is meant by a "curvature-line parametrization" of a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Could anyone explain to me what it means if a surface is *curvature-line parametrized*? What does it mean intuitively and how exactly is it different from any other parametrization?
I've been looking for the answer to this question for quite some time, but can't seem to find and understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a surface you can compute first and second fundamental forms. Those allows to approximate locally the surface by a polynomial surface of degree two.

In general case, this "approximation surface" has at each point  two directions (in the tangency plane) for which the curvature is maximum. If you use for parameterization of your surface parameters that are in the direction of those lines, you get a curvature line parameterization.

This is not alwyas uniquelly defined. Take the example of a shere. You won't be able to define uniquelly at a point of the sphere two directions with maximum curvture, the curvature being the same in all directions.

Finding curvature line parameterization can be done by solving partial differential equations.

Comment: How is the curvature-line parametrized surface different from another parametrization?

Comment: I got it now, thanks a lot for the answer!